# How can I know what methods/properties are available on top level MEL exception variable in Mule

Tags: mule

I have just used `#[exception.causeException]` in `<catch-exception-strategy>` so far (Mule 3.3.0). What other properties/methods are available on `exception`? Is there any documentation/API to know that.

I want to know that for other top level variables also available in MEL referenced [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/MEL+Cheat+Sheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exception` variable is bound to the `Throwable` that's set on the `MuleMessage`'s exception payload. So basically any field of the particular sub-class of `Throwable` you're dealing with will be available.

In your case, `causeException` comes from `getCauseException()` on Mule's [MessagingException](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/MessagingException.html).

For the 4 top level variables (`server`, `mule`, `app`, `message`) the fields are shown in the columns below the names in the page you linked.

Comment: Totally agree with you, and thats where I started looking initially but couldn't find any `getCauseException()` on `Throwable`. Only if I could understand mystery behind Mule

Comment: I've extended my answer to explain the origin of `getCauseException()`.